# C# Visual Studio 2013 Partial Line Coverage False Positive

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

IDE: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.
Language: C#
OS: Windows 8

Visual Studio code coverage is marking one of my lines as partially covered when I believe it shouldn't when it handles the "&&" operator. and I simplified the logic to demonstrate the issue.

Consider the following test function:

```
public static bool test(bool a, bool b)
{
    if (a && b) // Subject Line
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now consider the following test code:

```
test(true, true);
```

Visual studio will report the subject line as partially covered. I expect it to only be flagged as partial for the test(false, true) or test(false, false) cases. I can get it to flag as covered using the one following sequences:

```
test(true, true);
test(false, true);
```

or

```
test(true, true);
test(false, false);
```

I further simplified the issue. The following subject line is marked as partial:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = true;
if (a && b){} // Subject line
```

The following subject line is marked as covered:

```
bool b = true;
if (true && b){} // Subject line
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The return false is not hit.  Here is an alternative where every line is covered.

```
public static bool test(bool a, bool b)
{
    return (a && b);
}
```

Comment: That's cool.  It is not line by line its really different paths through the if statement.  If you try all 4 conditions you get 100% coverage.  I am going to try this in native.

Comment: Native says its 100% code coverage with true true.  My guess is this was because this was added way later.  
This article explains the reasons more. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398(v=vs.90).aspx